# mutate with if without else

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to mutate column values with if statement rather than ifelse statement. Since, I didn't find the right statement, I tried this : I have a dataframe `test`

```
index
A lunch
B kunch
```

I run

```
tmp<-mutate(test,index=ifelse(index == "kunch","flunch",test$index))
```

and I get this for `tmp`

index
1      2
2 flunch

How can I preserve the value `lunch` ?

edit :

```
structure(list(index = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("kunch", 
"lunch"), class = "factor")), .Names = "index", row.names = c("A", 
"B"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @HubertL here it is in the edit section

Comment: @HubertL thank you very much, could you provide the answer so I can accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "flunch" is of type `character`, `ifelse` returns a vector of `character`. It needs to convert index which is a `factor`, but it doesn't do it right with `as.character`, so yo have to do it yourself:

```
tmp <- mutate(test,index=ifelse(index=="kunch", "flunch", as.character(index)))
```

If you need to keep `index` as a `factor`, you can then:

```
tmp$index <- as.factor(tmp$index)
```

#### Edit

You can also simply change the value of the `level`:

```
levels(test$index)[levels(test$index)=="kunch"] <- "flunch"
```